# Expected { at end of input

Tags: c++

I have moved from Java to CPP and am struggling to wrap my head around structuring constructor chaining, which I think is the sourceof my issues.

My header file is as follows:

```
public:
GuidedTour();
GuidedTour(string ID, string desc, double fee, int size, string guide, string date)
            : Tour(ID, desc, fee);
```

And my cpp file is as follows:

```
 GuidedTour(string ID, string desc, double fee, int size, string guide, string date)
            : Tour(ID, desc, fee) {
                this->tourSize = size;
                this ->tourGuide = guide;
                this -> tourDate = date;
                }
```

I am getting two errors:

```
guided_tour.h: In constructor 'GuidedTour::GuidedTour(std::string, std::string, double, int, std::string, std::string)':
guided_tour.h:17:25: error: expected '{' at end of input
guided_tour.cpp: At global scope:
guided_tour.cpp:5:19: error: expected ')' before 'ID'
```

Any insight here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any basic textbook on C++ should explain how to write constructors.

Comment: Remove the `: Tour(ID, desc, fee);` part from the header. That's part of the constructor's implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either define the constructor completely in the header file, or only declare it.

In other words, either do this *in the header file*:

```
GuidedTour(string ID, string desc, double fee, int size, string guide, string date)
        : Tour(ID, desc, fee) {
            this->tourSize = size;
            this ->tourGuide = guide;
            this -> tourDate = date;
            }
```

Or do this *in the header file*:

```
GuidedTour(string ID, string desc, double fee, int size, string guide, string date);
```

If you do the first, then of course you have to remove the constructor from the source file.

Right now, you kind of mix it, with having an initializer list in the header file. This makes the compiler expect a function body as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. in the header file, the constructor declaration does not allow "initialization lists".
   change it to `GuidedTour(string ID, string desc, double fee, int size, string guide, string date);`
2. in the cpp file the constructor implementation should be `GuidedTour::GuidedTour(...) : Tour(ID, desc, fee) {...}`

Comment: Just to clear things up: initialization lists **are** allowed in header files, but only if you implement the constructor completely.